# Unix shortcuts on Windows (ctrl-P ctrl-N ctrl-F ...)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently switched my habits to use the keyboard most of the time. Many times I use those commands in the title to avoid using the arrow keys. I even installed a vim-like chrome extension, and realized that those commands work in my macbook on every application (or most of them).

For example when I start typing on the chrome/firefox address bar and suggestions are shown, I can quickly select between them (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd>), fill the line (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>f</kbd>) or delete the line (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>u</kbd>). It became a very useful habit for me.

Recently I need to come back to windows with one computer and none of those work out of the linux-subsystem-for-windows's bash shell. I feel very weird working without those shortcuts.

Is there a way to activate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> send <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> send <kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> only in Chrome (or everywhere). I don't know what "fill the line" means so I can't say what the corresponding shortcut for it is on Windows.

Here is an AutoHotkey script for doing so:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

^p::Up
^n::Down
^u::Send +{Delete}
```

Just install the program and put this code in a `.ahk` file, then run the file.

To have it make the replacement everywhere, remove the first line.

Similarly you can make replacements for the rest of the shortcuts you want (you need to find their corresponding shortcuts on Windows first though).

Some relevant entries from the documentation of AutoHotkey:

- [A list of keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Modifier keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)

---

**Note**: the reason the third line in the script is different from the first two (uses [Send](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiPl8Pt5cXWAhVGtRQKHQNeBYMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fautohotkey.com%2Fdocs%2Fcommands%2FSend.htm&usg=AFQjCNHR40vo9YsdKsyUil15Er2bP0qMJQ) instead of just listing the new key combination) is that if you do it like the others, i.e.:

```
^u::+Delete
```

then when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, indeed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is sent to the application but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you're holding down to do it is still taken into account, so you actually get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, which would open the Clear Browsing Data window instead of deleting a line from the address bar suggestions.

Comment: Great answer. Helped a lot. I remember having used ahk for many tasks back in the past. Just tested and it works very well.

Comment: Great; good luck. =)